# How to stop shooting with "NSTimer"

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a character shooting and it's always on once you touch the screen but I want it to stop when you stop touching the screen. Right now when you touch the screen it will start the shooting, but it will not stop when you stop touching the screen.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        player.position.x = location.x
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnShot"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent: UIEvent){
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnShot"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: In `touchesEnded` you need to invalidate the timer you created in `touchesBegan`.

Answer (score 1):

To stop a repeating timer you need to invalidate it, for that keep `timer` as property and then schedule it in `touchesBegan`, and when you want to stop timer invalidate it in your case its `touchesEnded` method, you can `invalidate` timer like this.

```
if self.timer.valid
        {
            self.timer.invalidate()
            self.timer = nil
        }
```

Comment: it just gives me an error saying "timer" isnt a member

Comment: Because u dont have it as member variable... Then u can access it  with self, add it as property